Data policy openstreetmaps nominatim
We are using nominatim openstreetmaps via geopy and compliance has asked to proof that openstreetmaps does not store address data (these are clients address data) and if they do store then there is some purging mechanism in place. I went through the data policy of geopy that refers to the one of openstreetmaps and the one of openstreetmaps but it focuses on its browser usage rather than the API. Ideas on how to address this? Happy to write to the project itself if that is the best solution.
Thank you very much

If you are bound by compliance rules, you would have to either run your own Nominatim instance or get a third party provider that is compliant with your requirements (DPA, etc.). The public demo instance is not the right choice for you as it cannot meet any compliance rules.
